# Python: check if last value of list occurs more than once

Tags: python, list

Problem:

> Write a program that will search through a list to see if the last value in the list occurs
>   more than once. If the last value occurs more than once, return true. Otherwise, return false. If the list is
>   empty, return false.

My Code:

```
def go(list1):
for i in range(0,len(list1)):
    if list1[i] is list1[-1:]:
        return True
else:
    return False

print ( go( [-99,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,5] ) )
print ( go( [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,9] ) )
print ( go( [10,20,30,40,50,-11818,40,30,20,10] ) )
print ( go( [32767] ) )
print ( go( [7,7,7,7] ) )
print ( go( [9,10,-88,100,-555,1000] ) )
print ( go( [10,10,10,11,456,10,10] ) )
print ( go( [-111,1,2,3,9,11,20,30] ) )
print ( go( [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,0,-2,9,9] ) )
print ( go( [12,15,18,21,23,1000] ) )
print ( go( [250,19,17,15,13,11,10,9,6,3,2,1,250] ) )
print ( go( [] ) )
```

My Output:

```
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
```

Desired Output:

```
True
True
True
False
True
False
True
False
True
False
True
False
```

What am I doing wrong? Why am I getting False for all my outputs?

Comment: Use `==` instead of `is` to check for equality

Comment: Please don't answer in the comments.  If you have an answer to the question, post it as an answer.

Comment: BTW, `go` is a _terrible_ name for that function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not be using `is` here, because `is` does not check for equality of *values*, but instead for equality of *references*.

Instead you can use `arr[-1] in arr[:-1]` to see if the final value of your list is present anywhere else in the list.

```
x = [-99,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,5] 

def is_last_contained(arr):
  return arr[-1] in arr[:-1]

print(is_last_contained(x))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple errors in your code as written:

1. `range(0,len(list1))` should be `range(0,len(list1)-1)` since you don't want to compare the last element against itself.
2. `list1[-1:]` should be `list1[-1]`. The former selects a slice, the latter a single element.

That being said, @chrisz's solution is more Pythonic and concise :)

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that you're trying to compare an element with a slice of list. Another mistake is that you're using the keyword `is` instead of  `==`. In order to check whether the last element exists more than once in the list, you need to check if the current element is equal with the last element and their indices are different (which means that there more than one elements with the same value). My recommendation below:

```
def go(list1):
    length = len(list1)
    for i in range(0,length):
        if list1[i]==list1[-1] and not i==length-1:
            return True
    else:
        return False

print ( go( [-99,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,5] ) )
print ( go( [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,9] ) )
print ( go( [10,20,30,40,50,-11818,40,30,20,10] ) )
print ( go( [32767] ) )
print ( go( [7,7,7,7] ) )
print ( go( [9,10,-88,100,-555,1000] ) )
print ( go( [10,10,10,11,456,10,10] ) )
print ( go( [-111,1,2,3,9,11,20,30] ) )
print ( go( [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,0,-2,9,9] ) )
print ( go( [12,15,18,21,23,1000] ) )
print ( go( [250,19,17,15,13,11,10,9,6,3,2,1,250] ) )
print ( go( [] ) )
```

Output:

```
True
True
True
False
True
False
True
False
True
False
True
False
```